# JQuery validation using is() and multiple CSS classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, textarea, validation

Trying to debug something that basically .trim()'s, .val()'s and .length's a textarea input as HTML below (truncated):

```
<form id="Kontaktanfrage" method="post" action="tests/testform/">
...
<textarea cols="50" rows="8" id="el_12" name="FORM[Kontaktanfrage][el_12]" title="Ihre Nachricht: *" class="textarea required"></textarea>
...
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validateField(formId, fieldId) {
if (fieldId) {
    var element = "form#"+formId+" input#"+fieldId;
    var fieldValue = jQuery.trim(jQuery(element).val());
    var fieldLength = fieldValue.length;
    var fieldError = "";
    if ($(element).is('.textarea.required') && fieldLength == 0) {
        fieldError = "error message";
    }
}
```

}

The above `if` check is never `true`.

Using JQuery: 1.4.1.

Having seen other examples online, I can't see what the difference should be. Feel free to test it in FireBug at (http://www.initiat.de/tests/testform/). Any help appreciated, can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating your selector assuming that all of your fields are Input elements.  TextArea is a different element and your selector should reflect that. I don't think that performance will take a big hit if you change this line

`var element = "form#"+formId+" input#"+fieldId;`

to this

`var element = "form#"+formId+" #"+fieldId;`

Comment: Thanks Ben, I forgot all about textarea not technically being of type 'input', it's one of my biggest annoyances in HTML. Thanks for spotting it :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
.hasClass()
```

Comment: I need to check 2 classes, hasClass() only checks 2 if it in a literal order, not in any order. I need the flexibility

Comment: You could always go element.hasClass(class1) && element.hasClass(class2)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
if ($(element).hasClass('textarea') && $(element).hasClass('required') && fieldLength == 0) {
        fieldError = "error message";
    }
```